# How to know the current level of rescursion?

Tags: java, recursion

While debugging a recursive method, I want to know what level it is at. Give me some advices about this, be it code or IDE tools (preferably Eclipse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep counter, and it value will show the deepness level. Something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
void call() {
    counter++;
    // recursive call
    call()
    counter--;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse's debug view already shows you the stack of the thread. Just look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Make the method take an additional integer argument, starting at one and incrementing it whenever you go one level deeper.

Answer (score 0):

@Kayaman is right (+1)
However if your recursion is very deep it may be not convenient to count the depth manually. You can use `Expressions` view instead. Write there expression `new Throwable().getStackTrace().length`. This will give you your recursion depth + `n` where `n` is the number of method calls from `main` to the beginning of your recursion.